Proper way to save networks as a shapefile after 3.0?
It seems the networkx depreciated the nx.write_shpafter the version of 3.0. So what is the most write way write a networkx graph to shapefile?
For my case, my node names are the coordinates of the nodes.
There is a problem of using the momepy.nx_to_gdf. The generated shapefile uses the edge's gemometry attribute as the polyline's location. However, this geometry may not reflect the real points' positions if I did something like nx.contracted_nodes.
